# How to set a search_path default on a psql cmd execution?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm looking for an option to create an alias command for a psql console connection which allowed setting the search_path, but I am not finding any option on psql util, nor the option to execute a command without exiting. any idea?

I would like to avoid preconditions as setting environment options and have a oneliner if possible

Comment: I would like to know if its possible invoke psql "login" with the default schema set in the very same line. I dont want to return to shell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a PGOPTIONS-style connstring as an argument to `psql` instead of using the `-d`/`-h`/`-U`/`-p`/etc options. For your example:

```
psql 'host=myHost user=myUser dbname=myDb port=myPort options=--search_path=myschema'
```

or, if you prefer the URI style,

```
psql 'postgresql://myUser@myHost:myPort/myDb?options=--search_path%3dmyschema'
```

See [the "Connection strings" section of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) for details.

Answer (score 30):

I finally found it, its not a psql option, but it fits a oneliner: 
`PGOPTIONS=--search_path=myschema psql -h myHost -U myUser -dmyDb -p myPort`.

If anybody improves it with a working version call for both unix and windows ill approve

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `.psqlrc` file, which is run at psql startup:

```
$ echo 'set search_path to foo,bar' >> ~/.psqlrc
$ psql ...
```

Comment: Is it possible in one line? If not ill approve this one! Thanksss

Comment: @Whimusical you'd only need to do the .psqlrc thing one time

Answer (score 0):

one liner for Windows:

```
set PGOPTIONS=--search_path=MySchema& set PGPASSWORD=MyPassword& psql.exe --host=MyHost -d MyDatabase -U MyUser
```